# RMarkdown code evaluation until command

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using *RMarkdown* where I'm building my analysis. The final output will be an html document. Actually I've got a core code which will be the final document and, after the end, I've got many lines of code with chunks and sentences that **at the moment** are not useful, but could be included in the final document.

  *Does a command exist to say to RMarkdown to evaluate the code until that point?*

Not just like `eval=FALSE` for chunks (I've got also plain text), but something like `\end{document}` in *TeX*. I don't want just to comment plain text and put `eval=FALSE` as chunks options.

I tried to google and read in the *RMarkdown* documentation, but I found nothing.

Thanks everybody! And forgive me for my poor English...

Comment: you could use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval=FALSE)` to set eval=FALSE for all chunks after the command ; I have no idea how to do that easily for the text.

Comment: Thank's @scoa. I know this use of `chunk$set`, and in fact I use it to not evaluate my code not needed and save time.

Comment: Not exactly what toy are asking for but since it will still evaluate the text but not show it in HTML is using HTML comment `<!---text--->`

Comment: @Daniel Winkler this is something like drmariod reply. I prefer CL. solution, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `knit_exit()`:

> Sometimes we may want to exit the knitting process early, and completely ignore the rest of the document. This function provides a mechanism to terminate `knit()`.

Example:

````
Text.

```{r}
print(1)
```

More text.

```{r}
knitr::knit_exit()
```

Ignored.

```{r}
print("Ignored.")
```
````

Everything after `knit_exit()` will be ignored. This works for all output formats.

The code above produces:

[image]

Comment: @SimoneMarini No worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to get this in both document types. So if you want to create PDFs, go for the first example and do not use `<!-- -->`. In HTML you can leave both comment characters inside the document.

What about this for PDF

````
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mario Dejung <m.dejung@imb.de>"
date: "28 Sep 2016"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: \usepackage{comment}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\begin{comment}

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\end{comment}
````

And this for HTML

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mario Dejung <m.dejung@imb.de>"
date: "28 Sep 2016"
output: html_document
header-includes: \usepackage{comment}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

<!--

\begin{comment}

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\end{comment}

-->
````

Comment: Nice solutions. I think I will use also them in future, but at present I was searching for something like @CL. reply. Thanks anyway!